# Error when implementing IDbContextFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hello when I tried to add a migration in the cmd to my web app I had an error:

"Consider using IDbContextFactory to override the initialization of the DbContext at design time.

To solve it I referred to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-idbcontextfactorytcontext

So I added a factory called TemporaryDbContextFactory

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

namespace _3610Project.Models
{
    public class TemporaryDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<ProjectContext>
    {
        public ProjectContext Create()
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ProjectContext>();
            builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=pinchdb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            return new ProjectContext(builder.Options);
        }

    }
}
```

However in the TemporaryDBContextFactory I am getting an error that says I need to implement the interface and recommends inserting the code below instead of my original method.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: That sure looks like you implemented the interface correctly to me.  What is the "code below" that it suggests instead?

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7175.

Comment: I got it working. Strangely the person that answered my question deleted the answer post. It required using DbContextOptions as a parameter in the create function. Never used it inside the method though. Thanks for your support!